#nullable enable causes SqlNullValueException
A build warning message caused me to try adding the #nullable enable directive to my data entity class.
However I found this causes an SqlNullValueException when the following code runs.
var customerId = 5 // a valid key
var db = GetMyDbContext() // my code to get the DbContext
var cust = db.MyExtCustomers.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(x => x.CustomerID == customerId);

The exception message is

System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: 'Data is Null. This method
or property cannot be called on Null values.'


The call stack is
    Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll!Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(int i) Line 2122  C#
    [Lightweight Function]  
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable<Entities.MYEXTCustomer>.Enumerator.MoveNext()    Unknown
    System.Linq.dll!System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetSingle<Entities.MYEXTCustomer>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Entities.MYEXTCustomer> source, out bool found) Line 7391    C#
    [Lightweight Function]  
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute<Entities.MYEXTCustomer>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression query)  Unknown
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute<Entities.MYEXTCustomer>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression)   Unknown
    dll!Helpers.DataAccessStd2.MakeReadOnlyProperties(string connectionString, int jobId) Line 439  C#

Is this error by design? How should I tackle refactoring my class?

Check that your entity is using null-able types, especially string? for any null-able columns in your table. In earlier EF/.Net versions, the string reference type was perfectly happy being linked to a null-able VARCHAR etc. Now EF will check null-ability and if the entity type is string it expects and enforces non-null-ability when you enable #nullable.
